# MS Access report showing &amp; instead of &

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2003

My Access 2003 database is showing `&amp;` instead of `&` on its reports. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two of them together e.g. "ham && eggs"